# Can't access XAMPP from other computers

Tags: xampp

I have installed xampp on my windows7(64bit). I can view my php website from my own computer but others within the same network can't open no matter they tried my own IP 192.168.x.xx/web folder or 127.0.0.1/web folder.

I did the same thing before in the 32bit win7 and it worked fine. I wonder how I can get it work?

I am pretty new to php and xampp so please give more detail. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Is your firewall configured correctly? That was my problem ;).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using windows than all you have to do is to go to Allow an app through Windows Firewall.click on Allow another app select Apache and mark public and private both .Again Allow another app this time select xampp and mark both public and private and is done click apply and exit .
Open cmd by pressing windows button+r write cmd than in cmd write ipconfig find out your ip . than open up your browser write down your ip http://192.168.1.x and you will be on the xampp startup page.if you want to access your local site simply put / infront of your ip e.g http://192.168.1.x/yousite.
Now you are able to access your website in private network computers .

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command and verify that your web server port is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0):

```
netstat -an | find "LISTEN"
```

It is really common for Tomcat to not listen on 0.0.0.0 until you specifically configure it to do so.

Other than that, verify the port is not being blocked by something.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 definitely wont work as that is the ip address of the local machine.
Are you perhaps missing a port number in your url, so from another computer try 192.168.x.x:80/index.html or similar

Answer (score 0):

May be your firewall configuration is on, change it, your issue will resolve. I too have the same issue and resolved it through this way.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Firewall Setting. It would be on So Please off window firewall Setting. I hope so it will be work.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

Press the "Windows + R" keys on your keyboard to open the "Run" dialog box.
Type "control" and press "Enter" to open the Control Panel.
In the Control Panel, select "System and Security."
Under "Windows Defender Firewall," click on "Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall."
Look for "Apache HTTP Server" or "httpd.exe" in the list. Ensure that both "Private" and "Public" boxes are checked.